# Hook to be used when creating a database table

Tags: database, hooks

I read the [Codex](http://codex.wordpress.org/Creating_Tables_with_Plugins) and some other tutorials describing the process of creating a new table for WordPress.

I thing that the steps are pretty straightforward; however, I'm encountering a small problem.

I am developing a theme (not a plugin) and I am creating some features which require a new WordPress table.

All the tutorials refer to the case when there is a separate plugin involved which must be activated. In that case, the hook looks something like this:

```
register_activation_hook(__FILE__,'my_plugin_data_tables_install');
```

The problem is that I don't have any plugin to be activated. What kind of hook should I use to make sure that the table is created correct and only once.

Comment: Do you really need a new DB table, or could your theme features go into the Options table?  See https://codex.wordpress.org/Options_API for more information.

Comment: You could look into [after_switch_theme](http://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference#Template_Actions), but it is rare that a theme should require special tables.

Comment: @PatJ I am creating a Slider inside the theme (it is not separated from the theme because I intend it to be the "Default Slider"). This Slides are quite different from a standard post and I thought that creating a new table for them would be a good decision.

Comment: @vancoder I am creating a Slider inside the theme (it is not separated from the theme because I intend it to be the "Default Slider"). This Slides are quite different from a standard post and I thought that creating a new table for them would be a good decision.

Comment: You might be wise to consider using [Custom Post Types](https://codex.wordpress.org/Post_Types#Custom_Post_Types) for your slides, then.

Comment: @PatJ actually I am using Custom Post Types. I am replacing the Default Add New with a new sub-page which does what I said before. Do you think it would be better to use Meta Boxes for that custom data?

Comment: I would recommend using Meta Boxes.  Have a look at the [Custom Metabox Library](https://github.com/jaredatch/Custom-Metaboxes-and-Fields-for-WordPress) if you haven't already -- it makes handling metabox stuff a lot easier, IMHO.

Comment: @PatJ Thanks! I will follow your advice after all :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As mentioned, `after_switch_theme` should be a pretty good choice. Your table create/update function will only run when you switch themes, which should be roughly like activating a plugin. If you use `dbDelta` to create and/or update the table there should be no issue with table creation. [From the Codex](http://codex.wordpress.org/Creating_Tables_with_Plugins):

```
global $wpdb;
$installed_ver = get_option( "jal_db_version" );

    if( $installed_ver != $jal_db_version ) {

      $sql = "CREATE TABLE $table_name (
         id mediumint(9) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
         time datetime DEFAULT '0000-00-00 00:00:00' NOT NULL,
         name tinytext NOT NULL,
         text text NOT NULL,
         url VARCHAR(100) DEFAULT '' NOT NULL,
         UNIQUE KEY id (id)
      );";

      require_once( ABSPATH . 'wp-admin/includes/upgrade.php' );
      dbDelta( $sql );

      update_option( "jal_db_version", $jal_db_version );
    }
```

That will check the hard-coded table version against the version stored in the database and create or update if necessary. Note: it will create ***or*** update based on calculations made by `dbDelta`. It will not try to create the same table twice. If the table already exists it will try to apply the differences between the existing table and the new table definition.